# Moving window correlation with gtools running() in while loop

Tags: r

I am trying to do a moving window correlation analysis between annual climate data and annual tree ring growth records (Basal Area Increments or BAI), using a while loop so the moving window correlation is performed with a climate variable (e.g. annual temperature) and each individual tree's records.

Here is some sample data:

```
bai1<-as.vector(c(12,11,14,20,17,18,12,12,8,31,15,8,21,13,10,19,11,14,20,17,18,12,12,13,12,11,14,20,17,18,12,12,8,31,15,8,21,13,10,19,11,14,20,17,18,12,12,13,7,NA))
bai2<-as.vector(c(NA,NA,NA,11,14,20,17,18,12,12,7,9,10,11,14,20,17,18,12,12,14,12,10,13,12,11,14,20,17,18,12,12,7,9,10,11,14,20,17,18,12,12,14,12,10,13,12,NA,NA,NA))
bai3<-as.vector(c(NA,NA,11,14,20,17,18,12,12,11,14,20,17,18,12,12,11,14,20,17,18,12,12,11,14,20,17,18,12,12,11,14,20,17,18,12,12,11,14,20,17,18,12,12,8,9,10,NA,NA,NA))
clim1<-as.vector(c(NA,NA,6,3,7,11,12,9,8,11,13,9,6,3,7,11,12,9,8,11,13,9,6,3,7,11,12,9,8,11,13,9,6,3,7,11,12,9,8,11,13,9,6,3,7,11,12,9,8,11))
clim2<-as.vector(c(NA,11,5,12,9,9,7,10,12,8,7,11,5,12,9,9,7,10,12,8,7,11,5,12,9,9,7,10,12,8,7,11,5,12,9,9,7,10,12,8,7,11,5,12,9,9,7,10,12,8))
clim3<-as.vector(c(11,8,12,5,6,8,5,9,10,7,11,8,12,5,6,8,5,9,10,7,11,8,12,5,6,8,5,9,10,7,11,8,12,5,6,8,5,9,10,7,11,8,12,5,6,8,5,9,NA,NA))

BAI<-data.frame(bai1, bai2, bai3)
CLIM<-data.frame(clim1,clim2,clim3)
```

In order to make the cor.test() work with the NA values that arise in some of the "windows", I have modified the function as follows (thanks to the assistance of others on SO):

```
cor_withN <- function(...) {
  res <- try(cor.test(...), silent=TRUE)
  if(class(res)=="try-error") NA else unclass(res)[c("estimate","p.value", "statistic", "parameter")]
}
```

I have successfully gotten this to work with the running() function from library(gtools) when I call out one individual tree and one particular climate variable. Here is the code, and a portion of the results

```
running(CLIM$clim1, BAI$bai1, fun=cor_withN, width=10, by=5, allow.fewer=TRUE, align=c("right"), simplify=TRUE)
$`1:1`
[1] NA

$`1:6`
$`1:6`$estimate
       cor 
-0.1916846 

$`1:6`$p.value
[1] 0.8083154

$`1:6`$statistic
         t 
-0.2762048 

$`1:6`$parameter
df 
 2
```

However, the output from this cor_withN() function that I've created is not the most user-friendly, and I'm struggling with how I can get the estimate, test statistic, p.value, and DF (parameter) into a dataframe that I can just use write.csv() to consolidate the results. I have a while loop that I previously wrote when just using cor.test between my climate and BAIs, but I have been unsuccessful at my attempts to use the running() command with the modified cor.test - cor_withN(). This is the loop code that I've been using for my other analysis:

```
x<-1
n<-names(BAI)
out<-as.numeric()
t<-as.numeric()
p<-as.numeric()
c<-as.numeric()
d<-as.numeric()
while (x<3.1)
  {
        temp<-cor.test(CLIM$clim1, BAI[,x])
    t<-temp[1]
    p<-temp[3]
    c<-temp[4]
    d<-temp[2]
    temp2<-c(n[x],t,p,c,d)
    out<-rbind(out,temp2)
    x<-x+1
    }
out
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how to call out the estimate, p.value, statistic, and parameter using something similar to the above loop, but instead of cor.test using the running() command with the cor_withN()? Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: What `running` function?

Comment: @BondedDust - the `running` function from package gtools

Comment: were you able to solve the problem?